# City trip planner tool

Tags: usa, online-resources, planning, vacations, portland

I am planning to go to a vacation trip (in the US) in which I want to make a number of stops in certain cities, several days each. I'd like to have a good plan of what to visit, how much time would it take, etc. So my question is - it there any online/offline tool specialized in this? I've looked through the site and there are references to road trip tools - which is not what I need, since I need specifically to plan things inside one city - and there's a reference to citytripplanner.com - but that site supports only limited number of cities. E.g. one of the cities I plan to visit is Portland, Oregon, and that site does not support it.

What I am looking for is to plan our day, accounting for public transportation, how much time roughly it takes for certain attractions, opening/closing times, etc. - something like a day planner but with a specific angle on specific city's realities. Of course, I could take a sheet of paper (or an online document in googledocs) and look up all the things and record them, but if there's a tool for conveniently organizing such information it would come very handy.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to answer this. If you were into zoos, for example, Portland and San Diego may have the best in the country. If not, they may not be worth a visit at all.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I'm more interested in the planning aspect than specific attractions. I.e. suppose I know roughly what I'd like to visit, but I'm not sure what to visit when or if I have enough time to visit both the zoo and some park in the same day. I.e. I look to get the (rough) schedule of the visit, kind of an individual planned tour, as a result of using such tool.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.tripit.com/uhp/mobile

is a very good choice. I use it for much of my work travel.